# VB.NET write/read data from text file

Tags: vb.net, text

This might be something that I am overlooking, as I am currently reading [a book on VB.NET](https://www.murach.com/shop/murach-s-visual-basic-2012-detail). I canceled a course in VB.Net recently because I was stuck on a problem and the lecturer did not get back to me with my questions that I had.

The objective was to create a business application with VB.NET that writes data from text boxes to a text file, seperated by a comma or a pipe. The user of the application must be able to select the directory where they want the file to be saved.

So I have for example 2 forms, one that captures the data for a client, and another form where you can select from a drop-down control, Now I know that **streamwriter** allows for the user to select self where they want the file to be saved, but how do I make the second form intelligent to know where the user saved the form and then reads the `client_id`, and fills the other data associated with the *client_id* to the text boxes in the form. I know **streamreader** is the one to use when you want to read data from a file, but how will **streamreader** know where the user will save the file to?

I am not doing the course any more, but I will keep on thinking what I could have done to actually get the project to work.

Comment: I don't see any attempt here. Check [ask], then edit your question to provide minimal info for question.

Comment: The more important the app or data is, the more likely a database would be a better choice than text files.  Text files can hold only text which means you have oodles of code converting values, prices, dates and the like to and from string.  Text files also are not random access.

Comment: @Plutonix, The thing is this was only for an assignment that I had to do and they specifically wanted us to write and read from text for the first part of the assignment, and for the second part we would have done a linq type connection to a database. But I canceled the course because the interaction between myself and the lecturer was non-existent, and it is a long distance course.

Comment: @raidensan, like I explained this was for a assignment, and because I don't do VB.Net day-to-day I really struggled even though I have a book to assist me, because this was a long distance course, there were no physical interaction between myself and the lecturer. Which means if I send an e-mail today I will be lucky to receive feedback in 2 weeks. it's not that I didn't try, I did try and  every time I added new records I overwrote the whole file, I asked the lecturer about this and he simply didn't reply so I cancelled the course, but I am still going through the book.

Comment: @JasonK Does the 2nd form open after selecting an option in the dropdown? If so, you need to pass the second form the path where the file was saved. If you overwrite the file every time, you are not opening it append mode.

Comment: @Jaxedin, No the dropdown is on the 2nd form, when I select a _client_id_ from the dropdown on the 2nd form I want the data to appear in the form, and I think I do use append for the write, I will show you when I get home. But then also **@Jaxedin** If this application will be used by someone other than myself, and they select the directory where to store the file, how will I know which directory the chose, and how will I pass the path to the second form?

Comment: @JasonK you can use 2 ways. Write the path to app settings and read it on the second form or create a sub new(path as string) on the 2nd form. So on the first form, you will call it like dim f2 as form2(mypath)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For writing to file

```
// Write single line to new file.
Using writer As New StreamWriter("C:\log.txt", True)
writer.WriteLine("Important data line 1")
End Using
```

For reading from file

```
// read from a file
Dim line As String
Using reader As New StreamReader("file.txt")
    line = reader.ReadLine()
End Using
Console.WriteLine(line)
```